# Please confirm I can use this ATtiny's IO as I intend to

Tags: avr, schematics

This is the first time I'm implementing a µController in a design (just have some experience with Arduino). So I just wanted to make sure that this will actually work instead of finding out once I start programming.

I'd like to use an [ATtiny861](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-2588-8-bit-avr-microcontrollers-tinyavr-attiny261-attiny461-attiny861_datasheet.pdf) to perform these main tasks:

- Communicate with a second µC via I²C as master
- Output an ~8.192 MHz (8.4 MHz max) clock to CLKIN of the [ADS131M03](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads131m03.pdf?ts=1629651522083&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS131M03)
- Output a 4 MHz clock to OSC1 of the [MCP2518FD](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/MCP2518FD-Data-Sheet-20006027A-1596921.pdf) CAN controller
- Get readings from an ADC ([ADS131M03](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads131m03.pdf?ts=1629651522083&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS131M03)) via SPI (mode 1)
- Get temperature readings from 3 sensors (connected to ADC1/4/10)
- Send those readings to the CAN controller ([MCP2518FD](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/MCP2518FD-Data-Sheet-20006027A-1596921.pdf)) via SPI (mode 1)

I'm mostly concerned with whether I'll be able to simultaneously get an 8.192 and a 4 MHz clock from OC1D and OC1B respectively. I'm also confused by there being 2 three-wire interface (DI/DO/USCK) sets of pins (PB0/1/2 and PA0/1/2), with only one of those being labeled with MOSI/MISO/SCK. I'm not sure if I can connect the SPI devices and the ISP header to either one, but I don't really have a choice here since one of them is occupied by the I²C lines (I could use software I²C).

The temperature sensors tolerate 12 V, I assume this will be necessary to program the µC since the reset pin is occupied.

Also, I rearranged lots of pins on the device's symbols to make the wiring on the schematic neater. Is this common practice or should I avoid it? I think it would be nearly impossible to keep the schematic somewhat readable if I couldn't move the pins.

[image: schematic]

Comment: 32 kHz is your GCD of 4 MHz and 8.192 MHz. I don't know anything about the timer systems in your MCU (yet.) But I have other questions, such as how much phase difference you want to allow between these clocks and do they need to be precisely locked in the sense that is always exactly 125 4 MHz clocks for every 256 8.192 MHz clocks, or can that be allowed to vary somewhat. Stuff like that. Lots of details would help here. But yes, you've put your finger on at least one right thing to be worried over.

Comment: @jonk The 4 MHz clock for the CAN controller should be fairly accurate, but the 8.192 MHz clock can be anything up to 8.4 MHz according to the datasheet. So I think 8.2 MHz would be a good choice. I’ll edit the question. Phase doesn’t matter.

Comment: Also please note that  I²C & SPI share the same peripheral - USI. You can't use both at the same time in hardware mode, as you have to switch USI mode & pins.

Comment: @NStorm Y2 is part 'SG5032CCN_20.000000M-HJGA3'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm mostly concerned with whether I'll be able to simultaneously get
> an 8.192 and a 4 MHz clock from OC1D and OC1B respectively
> So I think 8.2 MHz would be a good choice. I’ll edit the question.

I don't think you can get that on the same Timer1. And as you need accurate 4 MHz clock you can't use an interrupt-driver Timer0 output. If you can accept 8 MHz on your ~8.192 clock that is pretty easily doable. I.e. 4 MHz + 8 MHz output from PLL clocked Timer1.

> I'm also confused by there being 2 three-wire interface (DI/DO/USCK)
> sets of pins (PB0/1/2 and PA0/1/2), with only one of those being
> labeled with MOSI/MISO/SCK

Take a look at USIPP register description of the datasheet. It explains you can select either of these. As for the labels, refer to ports A & B description. DI = MISO, DO = MOSI, SCL = SCK.

You can connect ISP & SPI slaves on the same SPI bus. But I think you need to pull-up your ADC !CS pin to 3.3V to avoid it being selected during SPI flashing of MCU.

> Also, I rearranged lots of pins on the device's symbols to make the
> wiring on the schematic neater. Is this common practice or should I
> avoid it? I think it would be nearly impossible to keep the schematic
> somewhat readable if I couldn't move the pins.

Not really a common thing. It's actually rather confusing. You can just use a terminals instead to have a neat looking schematics without rearranging the pins. You're already using some but only for "external" inputs & outpus. But why just don't use them in-scheme? Just something like this:
[image: Internal terminals example]

In this example it's just connect to external header J1, but it can be connected to any IC same way.

Comment: Thanks, will take this all into account. 8 MHz is fine, that's still 97.7% the original sample rate. I was aware DI = MISO, ... but was wondering why only PB0/1/2 were labeled with MOSI/... while PA0/1/2 aren't. USIPP description states PB is default so I assume that's why.

Comment: @Cecemel The ones labelled MISO/MOSI/SCLK specifically are the ones used for programming (the ISP programmer uses SPI).